# Append a variable value to cv2.imwrite function

Tags: python, opencv

I want to append a value of a string variable into `cv2.imwrite()` function

I have made a code to extract frames from video and check if my target object is present in the frame or not. Currently the frames in which the target is found are saved as frame0, frame1 and so on. Below is my code for the same

```
def target_non_target(input_frames_folder,model_file):

    count=0
    folders = glob(input_frames_folder)

    img_list = []

    for folder in folders:
        for f in glob(folder+"/*.jpg"):
            img_list.append(f)


    for i in range(len(img_list)):
        print(img_list[i])
        v1=os.path.basename(img_list[i])
        print(v1)
        img_name = os.path.splitext(v1)[0]
        print(img_name)
        image = cv2.imread(img_list[i])
        orig = image.copy()

        image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))
        image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
        image = img_to_array(image)
        image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)


        print("[INFO] loading network...")
        model = load_model(model_file)


        (non_target, target) = model.predict(image)[0]

        if target > non_target:
            label = "Target"

        else:
            label = "Non Target"

        probab = target if target > non_target else non_target
        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, probab * 100)


        output = imutils.resize(orig, width=400)
        cv2.putText(output, label, (10, 25),  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        if target > non_target:
            cv2.imwrite("C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\Target_images_new\\frame%d.jpg"%count,orig)
            count += 1
    #cv2.imshow("Output", output)
        cv2.waitKey(0)



frames_folder = ("C:\\Python36\\videos\\videos_new\\*")

model = ("C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\target_non_target.model")

target_check = target_non_target(frames_folder,model)
```

Currently the frames in which the target object is found are saved as frame0, frame1,etc. I want to save the frame with the original name of the image which comes in the variable IMG_NAME. How can i append it to the `cv2.imwrite()` function. My few previous attempts gave me this error

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: `%d` means "digit" so if you try to just change `%count` to `%img_name` it's not going to format correctly---you need to use `%s` in your string if you want the string to contain the `img_name` string.

Comment: Your question is definitely not clear: you want to change the name of the output file? `cv2.imwrite` has nothing to do with the filename. Just make a [mcve] with just the filename handling and try to use `os.path.join`, or `%s` in the string formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your string formatting when you save a frame with `cv2.imwrite()`. Currently your formatting is `%d` which is trying to use a integer when it should be a string. You can either use `%s` or use the built in [format()](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python) function.

Change

```
cv2.imwrite("C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\Target_images_new\\frame%d.jpg"%count,orig)
```

to

```
cv2.imwrite("C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\Target_images_new\\frame{}.jpg".format(img_name),orig)
```